# Bind to collection of string with converter

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a next code:

```
class MyViewModel 
{
    public List<string> Items {get;set;}
}
```

and xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

It works perfectly.
Now I need to add some conversion:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource WorldBestConverter}}" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

And it does not works. I can change Items property to List< SomeObj> where SomeObj is class contained property Value and use it next way:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource WorldBestConverter}}" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

But I don't want to introduce new class just for this situation.
How can I bind to current List with conversion?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Explain your problem clearly.

Comment: It's pretty clear, actually: I want to bind to List<string> instead of List<MyObj>. MyObj contains property Value and I can write {Binding Value} but I don't wanna

Comment: Can you post more code?. Are you trying to concatenate strings and display in the TextBloxk using converter?

Comment: I rewrited question, take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add . for Binding. Refer the below code.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource myConv}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```